# ScrollTo jQuery where to put?

Tags: jquery, button, html, scrollto

I want to use the following jQuery script on my website:

```
$('#page2').ScrollTo({
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'linear'
});"
```

The idea is to have button that redirects people to a div somewhere else on my page. I found the jQuery script above but have no clue where to put it..

Comment: You need to put it at whatever point you want the scrolling to occur. For example, you could put it in an event handler for a click event.

Comment: You will also have to include the ScrollTo plugin.

Comment: Yes, I have that covered: 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollto.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry I didn't get any more useful feedback. Eventually I exactly found what I was looking for on http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/how-to-jquery-scroll-to-anchor-and-scroll-to-top-simple/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a button with the id 'scroller', you would put something like the following on your page:

```
$(function(){
    $('#scroller').click(function(){
         $('#page2').scrollTo({
             duration: 2000,
             easing: 'linear'
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that part after your explanation but now I'm questioning how my link would look like. Something like this? <a href="#" id="scroller"></a>